# Como fazer com CSS um Linear-Gradiente que tenha valores em PX e % ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Tenho uma situação que é a seguinte, tenho um `linear-gradiente` em um elemento, porém eu quero que a primeira e a última parte desse gradiente tenham 100px de uma cor só, e o meio dele seja sempre 100% completado por uma outra cor.

Para deixar mais claro fiz essa imagem. Repare que usando apenas **10% 90% 10%**, se o elemento for de larguras diferentes a largura da "coluna" da esquerda e direta vão mudar de proporção.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu queria era **100px 100% 100px**, com um valor fixo que não deve mudar se o elemento for mais largo ou estreito...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então como eu mesclaria valores em `PX` e `%` dentro do gradiente de forma a ter a primeira e a última parte com valores em `PX` que não vai variar conforme a largura, porém com o meio ocupando o restante do espaço?

Segue o código que usei nos exemplos:

```css
.box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 10%, blue 10%, blue 90%, red 90%);
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como não tive uma resposta, vou postar a solução que cheguei para resolver o problema.

Usei uma função de `calc()`, na cor do meio do gradiente para determinar que o tamanho dele seria `100% - 50px`, onde `50px` e a largura que eu gostaria de ter na última parte do gradiente. Dessa forma eu consegui duas "colunas" de tamanho fixo, pois não estão em `%`, com valores em porcentagem a largura das "colunas" variava de acordo com a largura do *container*.

O resultado ficou assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código conforme imagem acima:

```css
.box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,red 50px, blue 50px, blue calc(100% - 50px), red calc(100% - 50px))
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```